# python dataframe draw graph of value per row

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and 50 rows.

```
    A   B
1   5   9
2   4   2
3   7   1 
...
```

I want to draw a graph, in which X-axis will be the index, red line will be the value of A at that point, and blue line will be the value of B.

What's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)?

```
print(df)
  A  B
1  5  9
2  4  2
3  7  1
```

`df.plot(color=['red','blue'])`

[image]

Comment: you can edit your answer as per OP question. Color of A needs to be red and B to be blue.

Comment: Thanks @meW didn't notice the colour requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `matplotlib`:

```
a = np.arange(50)
np.random.shuffle(a)
b = np.linspace(50, 100, 50)
np.random.shuffle(b)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b})

plt.plot(df.index, df.B, label='B')
plt.plot(df.index, df.A, c='r', label='A')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]